# Separate Text Field into new rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm running a query against a remote MySql server. It basically includes a field that is semi structured (Text field).
Each value is on a new line:

```
uVal = 'Marvin'
uConfigPath = .F.
```

Etc etc

I want to be able to query the values and add a new column in my returned adaptor per item name, i.e.: `uVal` would be added as a colum and so would `uConfigPath`, but I'm failing badly. The query runs fine to select the rows I want but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: i'm not understanding the question, you'll have to explain some more. is "uVal = 'Marvin'
uConfigPath = .F." stored in a single entry in a db table? and uVal and uConfigPath are *also* columns in a db table?

Comment: I wan't to help but I really do not understand what your problem is.

Comment: There is 1 text field called Config in a table.